# How to draw a line graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, line

How to draw a graph like below and where should I start from?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I particularly like Zarko's answer but I am lazy and like to let LaTeX do the work for me so I would do this by defining a `linegraph` pic so that I could draw the line graph using the command:

```
\pic{linegraph={1,2,1,3,1,0.5,1.5}};
```

that, as above, results in the graph:

[image]

In particular, the minimum and maximum values are marked automatically. Here is the code, which used ferahfeza's answer as the starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\tikzset{
  pics/linegraph/.style = {
    code = {
       \def\mymax{-1000}
       \def\mymin{1000}
       \foreach \y in {#1} { % determine min and max values
         \pgfmathparse{max(\y,\mymax)}\xdef\mymax{\pgfmathresult}
         \pgfmathparse{min(\y,\mymin)}\xdef\mymin{\pgfmathresult}
       }
       \foreach \y [count=\c] in {#1} {
           % use \pgfmathparse to determine the appropriate label
           \pgfmathparse{\y==\mymax}
           \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\def\mylabel{\text{max}}
           \else
             \pgfmathparse{\y==\mymin}
             \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\def\mylabel{\text{min}}
             \else\def\mylabel{\c}
             \fi
           \fi
           % draw the line
           \draw [->,densely dashed](\c,0)--++(90:\y) node[above]{$x_{\mylabel}$};
       }
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % Draw the axes
      \draw [<->] (0,4)node[right]{$y$}|-(8,0)node[right]{$x$};

      % draw the line graph
      \pic{linegraph={1,2,1,3,1,0.5,1.5}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There is a very small amount of pain in determining whether a given point is at the maximum or minimum value and the code will automatically mark multiple maximums and minimums. Note that I have used the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package `\text` command so that `max` and `min` are printed as text and not mathematics.

If the x-coordinates are not given by the consecutive integers then it is easy to modify the code above so that it would accepts input of the form:

```
\pic{linegraph={0.9/1,2/2,3.1/1,3/53,4/1,5.2/0.5,6.3/1.5}};
```

That is, a comma separated list of `x` and `y` values.

Of course, if you are only drawing one of these graphs then perhaps it is not worth all of the effort! If you are drawing two or more of these then I would wrap all of the code inside a macro so that you could just type `\LineGraph{1,2,1,3,1,0.5,1.5}` :)

**EDIT**

Here is a macro version that also draws appropriately sized axes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\tikzset{
  pics/linegraph/.style = {
    code = {
       \def\mymax{-1000}
       \def\mymin{1000}
       \foreach \y in {#1} {
         \pgfmathparse{max(\y,\mymax)}\xdef\mymax{\pgfmathresult}
         \pgfmathparse{min(\y,\mymin)}\xdef\mymin{\pgfmathresult}
       }
       \foreach \y [count=\c] in {#1} {
           \pgfmathparse{\y==\mymax}
           \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\def\mylabel{\text{max}}
           \else
             \pgfmathparse{\y==\mymin}
             \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\def\mylabel{\text{min}}
             \else\def\mylabel{\c}
             \fi
           \fi
           \draw [->,densely dashed,blue](\c,0)--++(90:\y) node[above]{$x_{\mylabel}$};
           \xdef\lastC{\c}
       }
      % finally the axes
      \draw [<->] (0,\mymax+1)node[above]{$y$}|-(\lastC+1,0)node[right]{$x$};
    }
  }
}

\newcommand\LineGraph[1]{\tikz\pic at (0,0) {linegraph={#1}};}

\begin{document}

   \LineGraph{1,2,1,3,1,0.5,1.5}

\end{document}
```

The output is much the same as before except that I have adjusted for the questions in the comments.

Comment: would you able to make the plot in `blue` color, like the Zarko's answer?

Comment: @aan Sure just replace `\draw [->,densely dashed]...` with `\draw [->,densely dashed,blue]...`

Comment: thanks a lot. Your code is very well written. Between, how to put the `$y$` label on top of the arrow, rather than `right hand side` of the arrow? I had tried `draw [<->] (0,4)node[top]{$y$}`, but not working

Comment: @aan Try `node[above]{$y$}`. Btw, if you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: thanks a lot. Yours code is quite good.

Answer (score 9):

Using `\pic` definition.

```
pics/lines/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{
```

Our `pic` command has three parameters.

> First parameter (#1) : *x* coordinate.
>
> Second parameter (#2) : Magnitude of vector.
>
> Third parameter (#3) : If this parameter is equal to 1001 or more one, the label of vector is *x_max* else is equal to 0, the label is *x_min*. For normal labeling, give any number, for example 1.

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
pics/lines/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{
    code={
   \ifnum #3>1000 
   \draw [->,densely dashed](#1,0)--++(90:#2)node[above]{$x_{max}$};
   \else 
   \ifnum #3=0
    \draw [->,densely dashed](#1,0)--++(90:#2)node[above]{$x_{min}$};
   \else 
       \draw [->,densely dashed](#1,0)--++(90:#2)node[above]{$x_{#1}$};
       \fi
       \fi
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw [<->] (0,4)node[right]{$y$}|-(8,0)node[right]{$x$};
\pic {lines={1-1-1}};
\pic {lines={2-2-1}};
\pic {lines={3-1-1}};
\pic {lines={4-3-1001}}; % <-- Max Value > 1000
\pic {lines={5-1-1}};
\pic {lines={6-0.5-0}};% <-- Min Value = 0
\pic {lines={7-1.5-1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ferehfeza, thanks. Can I know what is the meaning of `\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]`? I seemed cannot add in caption for this figure.

Comment: @aan, you welcome. It is for arrow styling. You can change it, for example `[>=stealth]` or whatever you want. You can check the TikZ manual.

Comment: @ferahfeze, thanks. i have another question, why unable to add caption in your code? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524629/why-unable-to-add-caption-of-figure-for-begintikzpicture-stealth

Comment: @aan, because you are in `standalone` class. Change your class, for example, to `article`. Or add `preview` option to `standalone` class.

Answer (score 4):

It should be easy to modify the following to something you want:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw the axes
    \draw [<->,thick] (0,2) node (yaxis) [above] {$y$}
    |- (3,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$x$};

    %Draw a coordinate
    \coordinate[label=$x_1$] (c) at (1,1);

    %Draw an arrow to the coordinate
    \draw[<-, dashed] (c) |- (xaxis);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code renders this:

[image: the graph]

I guess the `\draw[<-, dashed] (c) |- (xaxis);` was the hard part about this. And I'm also not sure if this is the proper way to do this. In my opinion this looks a little messy. It would be nice if we could get some clarification about this by someone else.

Answer (score 4):

With the `pgfplots` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    axis line style={-Stealth},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    x label style={anchor=west},
    y label style={anchor=south},
    xmin=0, xmax=6.5,
    ymin=0, ymax=5.5,
    ticks=none,
            ]
\addplot +[nodes near coords, ycomb, 
           densely dashed, mark=triangle*,
           every mark/.append style={solid},
           point meta=explicit symbolic]
           table [meta=label] {x y label
                               1 2 $x_1$
                               2 3 $x_2$
                               3 1 $x_{\min}$
                               4 4 $x_4$
                               5 5 $x_{\max}$
                               6 3 $x_6$
                               };
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: @a]

Comment: Thanks. Would we able to put the `x` lable beside the `arrow` and not below the `arrow`?

Comment: @aan, of course. I  put it there since there is on your provided image. See edited answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. I want to ask one more question. is there a way to make the `x-axis` spread wider? Now is quite narrow and do not look like a graph. I had tried `    \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16}`, the `compat=1.16` is fixed right?

Comment: @ann, if you like, you can say `width=\linewidth˙ (in `\pgfplotsset`) and image width will be equal to text width. You can also move this option to options of `axis`.

Comment: Thanks. `width=\linewidth` seemed too large. Anyway, why I cannot change the number in `compat=1.16`. Is it fixed at `1.16`?

Comment: @ann, `compat=1.16` define version of used `pgfplots`.1.16 is temporary recent one and with it is written proposed MWE.