# Why unable to add caption of figure for \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a follow-up question from [How to draw a line graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524550/how-to-draw-a-line-graph/524570?noredirect=1#comment1327041_524570)

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\tikzset{%
pics/lines/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{
    code={
   \ifnum #3>1000 
   \draw [->,densely dashed](#1,0)--++(90:#2)node[above]{$x_{max}$};
   \else 
   \ifnum #3=0
    \draw [->,densely dashed](#1,0)--++(90:#2)node[above]{$x_{min}$};
   \else 
       \draw [->,densely dashed](#1,0)--++(90:#2)node[above]{$x_{#1}$};
       \fi
       \fi
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw [<->] (0,4)node[right]{$y$}|-(8,0)node[right]{$x$};
\pic {lines={1-1-1}};
\pic {lines={2-2-1}};
\pic {lines={3-1-1}};
\pic {lines={4-3-1001}}; % <-- Max Value > 1000
\pic {lines={5-1-1}};
\pic {lines={6-0.5-0}};% <-- Min Value = 0
\pic {lines={7-1.5-1}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I add a caption, it does not work and give error.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
...
\caption{Scdsadasdsities}
\label{fig:Scdsadasdsities}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
pics/lines/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{
    code={
   \ifnum #3>1000 
   \draw [->,densely dashed](#1,0)--++(90:#2)node[above]{$x_{max}$};
   \else 
   \ifnum #3=0
    \draw [->,densely dashed](#1,0)--++(90:#2)node[above]{$x_{min}$};
   \else 
       \draw [->,densely dashed](#1,0)--++(90:#2)node[above]{$x_{#1}$};
       \fi
       \fi
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw [<->] (0,4)node[right]{$y$}|-(8,0)node[right]{$x$};
\pic {lines={1-1-1}};
\pic {lines={2-2-1}};
\pic {lines={3-1-1}};
\pic {lines={4-3-1001}}; % <-- Max Value > 1000
\pic {lines={5-1-1}};
\pic {lines={6-0.5-0}};% <-- Min Value = 0
\pic {lines={7-1.5-1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Scdsadasdsities}
\label{fig:Scdsadasdsities}

\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace the `standalone`  class by `report`, for example. But I think what you want is to use `standalone` just to create a pdf with the TikZ picture and then insert that pdf in you text as a graphic, and then you can use `figure+caption`.

Comment: try class option preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class-option preview of standalone.

MWE

```
\documentclass[preview, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{%
pics/lines/.style args={#1-#2-#3}{
    code={
   \ifnum #3>1000 
   \draw [->,densely dashed](#1,0)--++(90:#2)node[above]{$x_{max}$};
   \else 
   \ifnum #3=0
    \draw [->,densely dashed](#1,0)--++(90:#2)node[above]{$x_{min}$};
   \else 
       \draw [->,densely dashed](#1,0)--++(90:#2)node[above]{$x_{#1}$};
       \fi
       \fi
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw [<->] (0,4)node[right]{$y$}|-(8,0)node[right]{$x$};
\pic {lines={1-1-1}};
\pic {lines={2-2-1}};
\pic {lines={3-1-1}};
\pic {lines={4-3-1001}}; % <-- Max Value > 1000
\pic {lines={5-1-1}};
\pic {lines={6-0.5-0}};% <-- Min Value = 0
\pic {lines={7-1.5-1}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Scdsadasdsities}
\label{fig:Scdsadasdsities}

\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Result

[image]